# How can I make my section smaller on phones without affecting the grid container and content inside?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a grid with a photo and text side-by-side and some wavey section breaks on either end. On desktop, it looks fine, but on mobile, the section is stretched too vertically. I figured out how to bring the wavey elements down with the @media selector but the section itself is still way too tall and max-height:; isn't changing it.

I tried changing the height constraints on the section and the grid container to limit the height of the section on mobile devices but it didn't have any effect. Other transformations seemed to work, however, so I'm not sure what interfering. There is also overflow, not sure why.

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 100px 20vw;
}

.grid-container {  
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    color: white;
    align-items:start;
}
.img {
    max-height: 100%;   
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    border: 10px solid #221D23;

}
@media (max-width: 576px) { 
    .tiny{
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="tiny">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
            <p>test</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img class="img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: please post a demo-able code sample

Comment: Just edited to include html segment and CSS should be demo-able